# SharePoint Online Rest API - Filter by boolean (yes/no)

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to simply apply a Boolean filter to a Rest API call that is based on a Yes/No

It has been documented in many locations that this functionality is broken for many years. I am unable to find any firm indication that it is indeed broken from Microsoft.

Has anyone been able to successfully achieve this in SharePoint online. I understand it is simple enough to filter the local collection, but this just feels sub-optimal in so many ways.

Examples:-

- items?$filter=YesNoColumn eq 1 - returns nothing
- items?$filter=YesNoColumn ne 0 - return everything
- items?$filter=YesNoColumn gt 0 - return nothing

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assuming the column is a Yes/No column, and not a column with "Yes" and "No" text, the following works for me in SharePoint Online:

Returns false items:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?$select=Title,YesNoColumn&$filter=YesNoColumn eq 0
```

Returns true items:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?$select=Title,YesNoColumn&$filter=YesNoColumn eq 1
```

Neither return items with a blank value.

Comment: It turns out I was dealing with a quirk regarding a PnPJs implementation.

Comment: This worked for me as well, using Graph SDK v4.14 to access SharePoint Online list data.

Answer (score 2):

Using the following pattern works in our implementation:

```
&$filter=(Category eq 'Work Description')and (Archived eq false)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?$select=Title,YesNoColumn&$filter=YesNoColumn eq 1
```

This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mike Smith - MCT gave the correct answer, I'll just add this:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?$select=Title,YesNoColumn&$filter=YesNoColumn eq null
```

you will get the blank data.

So, for all negative values as well as blank (or null) values you can use:

```
_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?$select=Title,YesNoColumn&$filter=YesNoColumn eq null or YesNoColumn eq 0
```

Answer (score 0):

We have to use expand property in REST API:

```
/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('TestList')/items?$select=IsActive&$expand=isActive&$filter=IsActive eq 1
```