# Power Flow automate, filtering Get Items for a Yes/No Column Value

Tags: power-automate, powerapp

I have a flow that creates items from list A into list B.

Say in list A, my column is "Repeatable" with a "Check" like so:

[image]

I am trying to only include checks in my list B

[image]

How do I filter for these in my flow?

I am trying to use this `Center eq 1463 and (AutomationType eq 'Management Reporting' or AutomationType eq 'Testing') and Repeatable eq 'Yes'.`  but it does not work.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: When do you want to run a flow (and create new item in list B)? Only when Center eq 1463 and (AutomationType eq 'Management Reporting' or AutomationType eq 'Testing') and Repeatable eq 'Yes'?? If yes, you can add triggee conditions using these values to "when an item is created" Trigger on list A

Comment: Sorry this is for a manual trigger.  It seems like it is not taking my repeatable eq Yes into account.

Comment: Repeatable is a yes/no column I should add.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is related to this answer: [SharePoint Online Rest API - Filter by boolean (yes/no)](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/242605/sharepoint-online-rest-api-filter-by-boolean-yes-no)

To filter by Yes/No which on the backend recognized as Boolean, you should use

- 0 for false/no (`Repeatable eq 0`),
- 1 for true/yes (`Repeatable eq 1`),
- and null for empty (`Repeatable eq null`).